# Realm could not delete data

Tags: java, android, realm

I want to delete a row and immediately add another row in Realm, I test some codes but Realm could not delete a row.
The below code is one of my tested code.

```
Realm realm2 = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
realm2.beginTransaction();
card.deleteFromRealm();
realm2.commitTransaction();
realm2.close();

Realm realm3 = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
realm3.beginTransaction();
Card newCard = realm3.createObject(Card.class, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
newCard.setCardNumber(cardNumber);
newCard.setCardToken(token);
newCard.setPasswordCount(pinLength);
realm3.commitTransaction();
realm3.close();
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: `realm2.commitTransaction();` ?

Comment: @APEXBoi I changed the code but the problem not solved.

Comment: version of Realm?

Comment: @APEXBoi I use `io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.10.0`